# sign android apk with existing .keystore

Tags: android, apk

I'm using Eclipse, and except for the default keystore path specified in windows->preferences->android->build, I didn't specify any other customized keystore path in eclipse.

I have the debug.keystore in two locations. one is in the default path, and the other say c:\customised_path. 
however, when i wanted to generate the cert:

> keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 20000 
>   it'll generate the debug.keystore in the java\bin folder.

and if i try:

```
C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin>keytool -genkey -v -keystore C:\default_path\.android\d
ebug.keystore
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:633)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:3
8)
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1185)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(KeyTool.java:620)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:172)
        at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:166)
```

it'll gimme the same error to generate the key in the customized path too.

i have debug.keystore in both folders still i'll have this:

```
C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin>keytool -list
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: C:\customiesed_path\.keystore
```

and
    C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin>keytool -list -keystore C:\the_default_path_specified_in_eclipse.keystore
    keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: C:\default_path

Eclipse is using the .keystore in the default folder to sign the apk, and i have the .keystore in the default folder, but it just doesn't allow me to sign it and gives me annoying error when I try to run my application.

Could somebody help here please?

Comment: Are you using the wrong keytool, look in other folders for a keytool

Comment: bingo! problem solved! it seems that the .keystore is somehow changed and after i re-download it, it works again. thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid that I'll have to answer this question myself. After inspecting everything on the developer.android website and all the help i can get from stackoverflow, I re-downloaded the .keystore that i need to use and run eclipse again. Now everything works normal. So next time someone has problems generating apk file using exist key, please take into consideration "run" in eclipse not from cmd as well as download a new keystore.

Comment: One more thing: signing in debug mode is different from release mode! eclipse users "run" to sign in debug mode. using command line won't work because they're simply for release!!!

Comment: Write it as an answer below. Then when you can mark is as answered.

Comment: @Blundell i can't... reputation lower than 100 so i can't answer my own question... you can help me with that and i'll mark it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bingo! problem solved! it seems that the .keystore is somehow changed and after I re-download it, it works again.

I re-downloaded the .keystore that I need to use and run eclipse again. Now everything works normal. So next time someone has problems generating apk file using an existing key, please take into consideration "run" in eclipse not from cmd as well as download a new keystore.

One more thing: signing in debug mode is different from release mode! Eclipse uses "run" to sign in debug mode. Using command line won't work because they're simply for release.