# keytool error java.io.ioexception invalid keystore format

Tags: android

Just can't seem to understand why I keep getting this.

I am using the export wizard to export and sign APK, but I keep getting this message.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using eclipse?
Try check below link, perhaps it might help.
[sign android apk with existing .keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607792/sign-android-apk-with-existing-keystore)

Thank you.